# script to download file from Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: bash, curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Trying to write script to download file from Amazon S3 bucket.

Having trouble with the example on the cURL site. The script below produces:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you
>   provided. Check your key and signing method.

Appreciate any help.

```
#!/bin/sh 
file="filename.php"
bucket="my-bucket"
resource="/${bucket}/${file}"
contentType="text/html"
dateValue="`date +'%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'`"
stringToSign="GET\n\n${contentType}\n${dateValue}\n${resource}"
s3Key='ABCABCABCABCABCABCAB'
s3Secret='xyzxyzyxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzx'
signature=`/bin/echo -en "$stringToSign" | openssl sha1 -hmac ${s3Secret} -      binary | base64`

curl -v -H "Host:lssngen-updates-east.s3.amazonaws.com" \
        -H "Date:${dateValue}" \
        -H "Content-Type:${contentType}" \
        -H "Authorization: AWS ${s3Key}:${signature}" \
        https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/${file}
```

Answer (score 16):

I write this bash script to download file from s3 (I download compressed file, you can change contentType to download other types of file)

```
#!/bin/sh 
outputFile="Your_PATH"
amzFile="AMAZON_FILE_PATH"
bucket="YOUR_BUCKET"
resource="/${bucket}/${amzFile}"
contentType="application/x-compressed-tar"
dateValue=`date -R`
stringToSign="GET\n\n${contentType}\n${dateValue}\n${resource}"
s3Key="YOUR_S3_KEY"
s3Secret="YOUR_S3SECRET"
signature=`echo -en ${stringToSign} | openssl sha1 -hmac ${s3Secret} -binary | base64`

curl  -H "Host: ${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com" \
     -H "Date: ${dateValue}" \
     -H "Content-Type: ${contentType}" \
     -H "Authorization: AWS ${s3Key}:${signature}" \
     https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/${amzFile} -o $outputFile
```

Comment: the $outputFile would contain header, so the file would not be exactly the same. :(

Comment: Generates file with following error message:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>TemporaryRedirect</Code><Message>Please re-send this request to the specified temporary endpoint. Continue to use the original request endpoint for future requests.</Message><Endpoint>test-buket-edge.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com</Endpoint><Bucket>test-buket-edge</Bucket><RequestId>BA7ABFAB1E84F97A</RequestId><HostId>1rkdVN4JvCd3m/4Ko/G66lTgfk04jsUB0e37vFvBq2UZZsYEvn6EJscjPfawKhZVlJqSrTJ2mnw=</HostId></Error>`

Answer (score 14):

Avoid signing the request yourself, a lot can go wrong or be hard to do. For example, you should check that the date is set to GMT or use x-amz-date headers.

Another approach is to use the [AWS Command Line Interface](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) and so use  `$ aws s3 cp` or `$ aws s3 sync`.

Answer (score 7):

As of August 2019 I found this to work. Has added region, and format of URL has changed.

```
#!/bin/sh 
outputFile="/PATH/TO/LOCALLY/SAVED/FILE"
amzFile="BUCKETPATH/TO/FILE"
region="YOUR-REGION"
bucket="SOME-BUCKET"
resource="/${bucket}/${amzFile}"
contentType="binary/octet-stream"
dateValue=`TZ=GMT date -R`
# You can leave our "TZ=GMT" if your system is already GMT (but don't have to)
stringToSign="GET\n\n${contentType}\n${dateValue}\n${resource}"
s3Key="ACCESS_KEY_ID"
s3Secret="SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
signature=`echo -en ${stringToSign} | openssl sha1 -hmac ${s3Secret} -binary | base64`
curl -H "Host: s3-${region}.amazonaws.com" \
     -H "Date: ${dateValue}" \
     -H "Content-Type: ${contentType}" \
     -H "Authorization: AWS ${s3Key}:${signature}" \
     https://s3-${region}.amazonaws.com/${bucket}/${amzFile} -o $outputFile
```

Answer (score 5):

One really effective solution (working on Dec 2021) is to use this script. Just need export keys before use (or copy it's values to the .sh file).

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKxxx
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=zzzz
```

### To download just run

```
./s3download.sh get s3://mybucket/myfile.txt myfile.txt
```

All you need to pass `get`, the s3 bucket along with file name, and output file.

### Script needed

Create a `s3download.sh` file, and `chmod +x s3download.sh`, to use on command above.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu
s3simple() {
  local command="$1"
  local url="$2"
  local file="${3:--}"

  # todo: nice error message if unsupported command?

  if [ "${url:0:5}" != "s3://" ]; then
    echo "Need an s3 url"
    return 1
  fi
  local path="${url:4}"

  if [ -z "${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID-}"  ]; then
    echo "Need AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID to be set"
    return 1
  fi

  if [ -z "${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY-}" ]; then
    echo "Need AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY to be set"
    return 1
  fi

  local method md5 args
  case "$command" in
  get)
    method="GET"
    md5=""
    args="-o $file"
    ;;
  put)
    method="PUT"
    if [ ! -f "$file" ]; then
      echo "file not found"
      exit 1
    fi
    md5="$(openssl md5 -binary $file | openssl base64)"
    args="-T $file -H Content-MD5:$md5"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Unsupported command"
    return 1
  esac

  local date="$(date -u '+%a, %e %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000')"
  local string_to_sign
  printf -v string_to_sign "%s\n%s\n\n%s\n%s" "$method" "$md5" "$date" "$path"
  local signature=$(echo -n "$string_to_sign" | openssl sha1 -binary -hmac "${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}" | openssl base64)
  local authorization="AWS ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}:${signature}"

  curl $args -s -f -H Date:"${date}" -H Authorization:"${authorization}" https://s3.amazonaws.com"${path}"
}

s3simple "$@"
```

You can find more information about the s3simple script [here](https://github.com/paulhammond/s3simple).

Comment: I followed the description. Not work for me.It says:
`The requested URL returned error: 403 `

Comment: @JafarAmini you could check 403 errors here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/

Comment: the best solution so far

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
# This works for cross region
outputFile="/PATH/TO/FILE"
awsFile="BUCKETPATH/TO/FILE"
bucket="SOME-BUCKET"
resource="/${bucket}/${awsFile}"
contentType="application/x-compressed-tar"
# Change the content type as desired
dateValue=`TZ=GMT date -R`
#Use dateValue=`date -R` if your TZ is already GMT
stringToSign="GET\n\n${contentType}\n${dateValue}\n${resource}"
s3Key="ACCESS_KEY_ID"
s3Secret="SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
signature=`echo -n ${stringToSign} | openssl sha1 -hmac ${s3Secret} -binary | base64`
curl -H "Host: ${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com" \
     -H "Date: ${dateValue}" \
     -H "Content-Type: ${contentType}" \
     -H "Authorization: AWS ${s3Key}:${signature}" \
     https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/${awsFile} -o $outputFile
```

Comment: I needed the `-e` option on `echo` (`echo -en ...`), as in **ytdm**'s answer.  I'm not sure if it was necessary, but I also used the plain `date -R` (without `TZ`).

Answer (score 1):

I created an [AWS signature v4 creator](https://gist.github.com/adrianbartyczak/1a51c9fa2aae60d860ca0d70bbc686db) in Bash. It does not provide code to download files from S3 however.

```bash
readonly AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='<your_access_key_id>'
readonly AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='<your_secret_access_key>'
readonly AWS_SERVICE='s3'
readonly AWS_REGION='us-east-1'
readonly AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME='<your_bucket_name>'
readonly AWS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT_URL="\
${AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME}.${AWS_SERVICE}.amazonaws.com"

# Create an SHA-256 hash in hexadecimal.
# Usage:
#   hash_sha256 <string>
function hash_sha256 {
  printf "${1}" | openssl dgst -sha256 | sed 's/^.* //'
}

# Create an SHA-256 hmac in hexadecimal format.
# Usage:
#   hmac_sha256 <key> <data>
function hmac_sha256 {
  key="$1"
  data="$2"
  printf "${data}" | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt "${key}" | \
      sed 's/^.* //'
}

readonly CURRENT_DATE_DAY="$(date -u '+%Y%m%d')"
readonly CURRENT_DATE_TIME="$(date -u '+%H%M%S')"
readonly CURRENT_DATE_ISO8601="${CURRENT_DATE_DAY}T${CURRENT_DATE_TIME}Z"

readonly HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD='GET'
readonly HTTP_REQUEST_PAYLOAD=''
readonly HTTP_REQUEST_PAYLOAD_HASH="$(printf "${HTTP_REQUEST_PAYLOAD}" | \
    openssl dgst -sha256 | sed 's/^.* //')"
readonly HTTP_CANONICAL_REQUEST_URI='/video_clips/0940.m3u8'
readonly HTTP_CANONICAL_REQUEST_QUERY_STRING=''
readonly HTTP_REQUEST_CONTENT_TYPE='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

readonly HTTP_CANONICAL_REQUEST_HEADERS="\
content-type:${HTTP_REQUEST_CONTENT_TYPE}
host:${AWS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT_URL}
x-amz-content-sha256:${HTTP_REQUEST_PAYLOAD_HASH}
x-amz-date:${CURRENT_DATE_ISO8601}"
# Note: The signed headers must match the canonical request headers.
readonly HTTP_REQUEST_SIGNED_HEADERS="\
content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date"

readonly HTTP_CANONICAL_REQUEST="\
${HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD}
${HTTP_CANONICAL_REQUEST_URI}
${HTTP_CANONICAL_REQUEST_QUERY_STRING}
${HTTP_CANONICAL_REQUEST_HEADERS}\n
${HTTP_REQUEST_SIGNED_HEADERS}
${HTTP_REQUEST_PAYLOAD_HASH}"

# Create the signature.
# Usage:
#   create_signature
function create_signature {
  stringToSign="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
${CURRENT_DATE_ISO8601}
${CURRENT_DATE_DAY}/${AWS_REGION}/${AWS_SERVICE}/aws4_request
$(hash_sha256 "${HTTP_CANONICAL_REQUEST}")"

  dateKey=$(hmac_sha256 key:"AWS4${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}" \
      "${CURRENT_DATE_DAY}")
  regionKey=$(hmac_sha256 hexkey:"${dateKey}" "${AWS_REGION}")
  serviceKey=$(hmac_sha256 hexkey:"${regionKey}" "${AWS_SERVICE}")
  signingKey=$(hmac_sha256 hexkey:"${serviceKey}" "aws4_request")

  printf "${stringToSign}" | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt \
      hexkey:"${signingKey}" | awk '{print $2}'
}

readonly SIGNATURE="$(create_signature)"

readonly HTTP_REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER="\
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}/${CURRENT_DATE_DAY}/\
${AWS_REGION}/${AWS_SERVICE}/aws4_request, \
SignedHeaders=${HTTP_REQUEST_SIGNED_HEADERS};x-amz-date, Signature=${SIGNATURE}"

curl -X "${HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD}" -v \
    "https://${AWS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT_URL}${HTTP_CANONICAL_REQUEST_URI}" \
    -H "Authorization: ${HTTP_REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER}" \
    -H "content-type: ${HTTP_REQUEST_CONTENT_TYPE}" \
    -H "x-amz-content-sha256: ${HTTP_REQUEST_PAYLOAD_HASH}" \
    -H "x-amz-date: ${CURRENT_DATE_ISO8601}"
```