# Can I download an object from private S3 bucket using https without making bucket or object public?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to download an object from a private S3 bucket using HTTPS. But the URL returns Access Denied.
Can I download an object using credentials(AccessKeyId & SecretAccessKey) via HTTPS?

Comment: Apply bucket policies which should provide you with complete bucket access and deny access to others , by which only you can download file directly from AWS s3 GUI or using sdk or curl with access token or via cli

Comment: I'm trying to download it from the URL. Is there any approach to download it with the URL using access and secret key?

Comment: Similar kind of request 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30876123/script-to-download-file-from-amazon-s3-bucket

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the AWS SDK class AmazonS3URI as per below:

```
URI fileToBeDownloaded = new URI(" https://s3.amazonaws.com/account-update/inputtest.csv"); 

AmazonS3URI s3URI = new AmazonS3URI(yourfileToBeDownloaded);

S3Object s3Object = s3Client.getObject(s3URI.getBucket(), s3URI.getKey());
```

Comment: Actually I'm trying it to download directly from URL in the browser like signed-URL. Is there any other approach do it?